# How to create mouse over popups for nodes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I've been trying to figure out how to make pop-up windows appear on the nodes of my Force Directed chart as you mouse over them. Does anyone know of a method to execute this? The chart is built using the D3 library.

Here is the chart. I'd like to add descriptive popups for each item for when you hover your mouse over them:

[image: Chart]

Here is an example from another Force Directed Chart

[image: Pop]

```
var   w = 1000,
      h = 1000;

var circleWidth = 5;

var palette = {
      "lightgray": "#819090",
      "gray": "#708284",
      "mediumgray": "#536870",
      "darkgray": "#475B62",

      "darkblue": "#0A2933",
      "darkerblue": "#042029",

      "paleryellow": "#FCF4DC",
      "paleyellow": "#EAE3CB",
      "yellow": "#A57706",
      "orange": "#BD3613",
      "red": "#D11C24",
      "pink": "#C61C6F",
      "purple": "#595AB7",
      "blue": "#2176C7",
      "green": "#259286",
      "yellowgreen": "#738A05"
  }

var nodes = [
      { name: "Stratification"},                  //0
      { name: "Racism", target:[0]},              //1
      { name: "Job Descrimination", target: [0]}, //2
      { name: "Zoning", target: [0]},             //3
      { name: "G.I. Bill", target: [0]},          //4
      { name: "Gentrification", target: [0]},     //5
      { name: "Education", target: [0]},          //6
      { name: "Redlining", target: [0]},          //7
      { name: "Digital Divide", target: [0]},     //8
      { name: "Whitewashing", target: [0]},       //9
      { name: "Budget Cuts", target: [0]},        //10
      { name: "Tithes", target: [0]},             //11
      { name: "Sexism", target: [0]},             //12
      { name: "Slavery", target: [0]},            //13
      { name: "Ghettoization", target: [0]},      //14
      { name: "Colorism", target: [0]},           //15
      { name: "Prison System", target: [0]},                   //16
      { name: "Jim Crow", target: [0]},           //17
      { name: "Police Brutality", target: [0]},   //18
      { name: "War on Drugs", target: [0]},       //19
      { name: "Anti-Immigration", target: [0]},   //20
      { name: "Sharecropping", target: [0]},      //21
      { name: "Class Division", target: [0]},     //22
      { name: "Religious Freedom Bill", target: [0]}, //23
      { name: "Tax Exemption", target: [0]},      //24
      { name: "Wage Gap", target: [0]},           //25
      { name: "Legacy Income", target: [0]},      //26
      { name: "Capitalism", target: [0]},         //27
      { name: "Sexual Orientation", target: [0]}, //28

];

var links = [];

for (var i = 0; i< nodes.length; i++) {
      if (nodes[i].target !== undefined) {
            for (var x = 0; x< nodes[i].target.length; x++ ) {
                  links.push({
                        source: nodes[i],
                        target: nodes[nodes[i].target[x]]
                  })
            }
      }
}

var myChart = d3.select('#chart')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', w)
        .attr('height', h)

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([])
    .gravity(0.3)
    .charge(-1000)
    .size([w, h])

var link = myChart.selectAll('line')
    .data(links).enter().append('line')
    .attr('stroke', palette.gray)

var node = myChart.selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes).enter()
    .append('g')
    .call(force.drag);

node.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', circleWidth )
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        if (i>0) { return palette.pink }
        else { return palette.blue }
    })

node.append('text')
    .text(function(d) { return d.name})
    .attr('font-family', 'Roboto Slab')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        if (i>0) { return palette.mediumgray}
        else { return palette.yellowgreen}
    })
    .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        if (i>0) { return circleWidth + 4 }
        else { return circleWidth -15 }
    })
    .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        if (i>0) { return circleWidth }
        else { return 8 }
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', function(d, i) {
        if (i>0) { return 'beginning' }
        else { return 'end'}
    })
    .attr('font-size',  function(d, i) {
        if (i>0) { return '1em' }
        else { return '1.8em'}
    })

force.on('tick', function(e) {
    node.attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        return 'translate('+ d.x +', '+ d.y +')';
    })

    link
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y })
})

force.start();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Part of an MCVE is listing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it -- people aren't going to want to type out your code manually! ;) It would also be helpful to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you for the suggestion! I just added the code.

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: @karthick I've already viewed that page, but it only shows you how to created a Force Directed chart. Not how to to create mouse over popups.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [d3-tip plugin](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip) as a starting point. This will give you mouseover tooltips with customisation.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is mouseover event handler.
Update your code for the circle with the mouseover handler

```
        node.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
            .attr('r', circleWidth )
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                if (i>0) { return palette.pink }
                else { return palette.blue }
            })
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {     
                div.transition()        
                    .duration(200)      
                    .style("opacity", .9);      
                div .html("<h5>description:</h5><p> " + description[d.name] +"</p>")    
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
                })                  
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
                div.transition()        
                    .duration(500)      
                    .style("opacity", 0);   
            });
```

http://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/OmqMQq

I am not sure which plugin or how you want to use for displaying the information. There are lot of tooltip plugins available. Hope this helps

Comment: I tried using that method but it didn't work unfortunately. And i'd like to have a window be displayed with a description of that item when the mouse hovers over it.